# Dúvida - HashMap

Tags: java, lista, arraylist, hashmap

Preciso percorrer uma lista de reservas de hotéis e, para cada reserva dessas, capturar o Evento que está associado a ela. Ao final do processo preciso dizer quantas reservas de hotel cada evento possui e finalmente jogar o resultado na tela. A ideia que tive foi usar `Map`. Porém estou tendo dificuldade em mapear a quantidade de reservas de cada evento com o evento correspondente.

A ideia é:

```
Evento  Quantidade de Reservas
X                 10
Y                 15
```

O que tenho feito até o momento é o seguinte:

```
int hotelReservationQtd = 0;
List<IHotelReservation> iHotelReservationList = Lists.newArrayList();

iHotelReservationList.addAll(this.hotelReservationDao.listAll());
iHotelReservationList.addAll(this.omnibeesHotelReservationDao.listAll());

Map<Event, Integer> hotelReservationMap = Maps.newHashMap();

for (IHotelReservation iHotelReservation: iHotelReservationList) {
    if (hotelReservationMap.containsKey(iHotelReservation.getEvent())) {
        hotelReservationMap.put(iHotelReservation.getEvent(), hotelReservationQtd++);
    }
}

this.result.include("hotelReservationMap", hotelReservationMap.values());
```

Comment: Essa forma de fazer me lembrou a collection Multiset da biblioteca Guava. Considere essa collection para o seu caso, caso ela lhe pareça apropriada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o código abaixo faz o que você quer, a principal alteração foi no `for`. No final, o map `hotelReservationMap` irá ter um Event como key e um Integer (>=1) como Value para cada key, contando quantas vezes um mesmo Event apareceu nas iterações do loop:

```
List<IHotelReservation> iHotelReservationList = Lists.newArrayList();

iHotelReservationList.addAll(this.hotelReservationDao.listAll());
iHotelReservationList.addAll(this.omnibeesHotelReservationDao.listAll());

Map<Event, Integer> hotelReservationMap = Maps.newHashMap();

for (IHotelReservation iHotelReservation : iHotelReservationList) {
    int hotelReservationQtd = 1;
    if (hotelReservationMap.containsKey(iHotelReservation.getEvent())) {
        hotelReservationQtd = hotelReservationMap.get(iHotelReservation.getEvent())+1;
    }
    hotelReservationMap.put(iHotelReservation.getEvent(), hotelReservationQtd);
}

this.result.include("hotelReservationMap", hotelReservationMap.values());
```

---

Para testar a lógica de funcionamento, criei um código que funciona de maneira similar, ele recebe uma lista de objetos `Pessoa` e conta quantas pessoas tem o mesmo nome, gerando um map que tem um `nome` como key e tem como value um `Integer` que diz quantas pessoas tem esse `nome`.

```
public class ContadorDeRepeticaoDeNomes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pessoa> listaDePessoas = new ArrayList<>();

        //Duas pessoas com o Nome João
        listaDePessoas.add(new Pessoa("João"));
        listaDePessoas.add(new Pessoa("João"));

        //Uma pessoa com o nome "Pedro"
        listaDePessoas.add(new Pessoa("Pedro"));

        //Três pessoas com o nome "Maria"
        listaDePessoas.add(new Pessoa("Maria"));
        listaDePessoas.add(new Pessoa("Maria"));
        listaDePessoas.add(new Pessoa("Maria"));

        //Uma pessoa com o nome "José"
        listaDePessoas.add(new Pessoa("José"));

        Map<String, Integer> nomesDePessoas = contarPessoasComMesmoNome(listaDePessoas);

        nomesDePessoas.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("Existem "+v+" Pessoas com o Nome "+k));

    }

    /**Retorna um Map com um "Nome" como chave, e, a quantidade de Pessoas que tem este nome como "Value"*/
    private static Map<String, Integer> contarPessoasComMesmoNome(List<Pessoa> listaDePessoas) {
        Map<String, Integer> nomesDePessoas = new HashMap<>();

        for (Pessoa pessoa : listaDePessoas) {
            int quantidadeDePessoasComEsteNome = 1;
            if (nomesDePessoas.containsKey(pessoa.nome)) {
                quantidadeDePessoasComEsteNome = nomesDePessoas.get(pessoa.nome)+1;
            }
            nomesDePessoas.put(pessoa.nome, quantidadeDePessoasComEsteNome);
        }

        return nomesDePessoas;
    }

    private static class Pessoa {
        String nome;

        public Pessoa(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }
    }
}
```

Ao executá-lo a Saída é como o esperado:

> Existem 2 Pessoas com o Nome João
>   Existem 1 Pessoas com o Nome José
>   Existem 1 Pessoas com o Nome Pedro
>   Existem 3 Pessoas com o Nome Maria